Deriving the DCT-II from the DFT
Recently, I was looking into the theory behind the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) when I frequently encountered the discrete cosine transform (DCT-II). Due to the similarities between the DFT and the DCT-II, I wondered how to derive the DCT-II from the DFT.
The DFT can be interpreted as the inner product of some input vector $\mathbf{x}=(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1})^\top\in\mathbb{C}^{N}$ with the orthogonal basis vector $\mathbf{f}_k=(1,\omega^k,\ldots,\omega^{(N-1)k})^\top\in\mathbb{C}^N$, where $ \omega=\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}/N}$, giving us
\begin{align}
\hat{x}_k=\langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{f}_k\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\omega^{nk}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\left[\cos{\left(\frac{2\pi nk}{N}\right)}-\mathrm{i}\sin{\left(\frac{2\pi nk}{N}\right)}\right].
\end{align}
Thus, the real part of $\hat{x}_k$ almost completely resembles the DCT-II coefficient $X_k$ of a real vector $\mathbf{X}=(X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_{N-1})^\top\in\mathbb{R}^N$, given by
\begin{align}
\hat{X}_k=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}X_n\cos{\left(\frac{2\pi(n+1/2)k}{N}\right)}. \tag{I}
\end{align}
My question: Do the cosines in the DCT-II form a new orthogonal basis in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and if so, why can we "ignore" the sines? Also, why do we use $n+1/2$ in (I) instead of just $n$?
